# Piwik API Calls

Tags: php, matomo

I'm creating a custom UI using the piwik API too call the various modules.

I'm basing it all on this php tutorial: http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/API/CallingTechniques

My question is: because there could be up too 10+ modules being called on one page is their a more efficient way to call them instead of the example in the above link?

If not, is there a way to display some sort of "loading..." text or something before the module is loaded as it can take sometime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the modules asynchronous. Try using jQuery Ajax function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. While loading you can easily display a loading image.